# May one buy from a store that serves basar b'chalav?

Tags: halacha, money, meat-and-milk

Chullin 115b provides several sources that one may not derive benefit from basar b'chalav.

Say that there's a shop that sells basar b'chalav, but also sells sealed bottles of water or kosher sodas. May I buy from this store? Is this called benefitting from basar b'chalav, since the drink was purchased by the store, whose profits were made from basar b'chalav, or do we say that this is a permissible way to "launder" the issur?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52626/discussion-on-question-by-donielf-may-one-buy-from-a-store-that-serves-basar-bc).

Comment: can you explain exactly how you are having benefit from the basar b'chalav in this situation? Or perhaps is the question that you mean to ask, "Is it permissible to purchase from a Jewish owned store that is benefiting from bas b'chalav"?

Comment: @Dude Take a look at the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52626/discussion-on-question-by-donielf-may-one-buy-from-a-store-that-serves-basar-bc) pertaining to this post.